# CSS confusion in one statement in my code

Tags: html, css, visual-web-developer

What is the meaning of `id^` in

> [id^="slide"]:checked+ .slide

This line was there in a CSS code and I am unable to figure out its meaning. Please help me to clear this doubt.

Answer (score 4):

^=, in this case, means "starts with". So this selector will look for anything that has an id starting with "slide", that's checked, and then apply to the `.slide` directly following it.

[Here's the MDN run-down of attribute selectors.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors) Closely related to `^=` are  `*=` (matches anywhere in the string) and `$=` (matches at the end of the string). And here's a demo!

```css
[id*="slide"] {
height: 30px;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
}

[id^="slide"] {
background: orange;
}

[id$="2"] {
background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide-1">#slide-1</div>
<div id="slide-2">#slide-2</div>
<div id="not-a-slide">#not-a-slide</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you got the info you needed, make sure to mark the answer as Accepted.